# How can I split a message in parts of similar size or smaller?

Tags: encryption

I have a 130-160 characters message that I need to split in say, 3 parts, and be able to reconstruct it by recovering all 3 parts. I also need that these parts are type-able, meaning that they can't be too long (I mean not much longer than the original message), and they can't contain weird characters.

I tried with [Shamir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) but the results are too long. I used [PassGuardian](http://passguardian.com/) for that.

Any suggestions?

You can also help me with the tags so the right people is able to find this post.

Comment: If the $160$ characters are arbitrary among $256$ values, and the set of type-able characters has $64$ values, then by a counting argument you need one of the $3$ parts to have $\lceil{160\over 3}\cdot{{\log_2(256)}\over{\log_2(64)}}\rceil=72$ characters, which is hardly type-able. Without _arbitrary_, you could compress the message beforehand.

Comment: @fgrieu I can type up to the length of the original message, so 72 characters is fine. But how do I do that? (does the algorithm have a name?) I'm sorry I'm not a cryptographer, just a developer.

Comment: What are your security goals? From the description it seems like taking the 130-160 character message $m=m_1||m_2||m_3$ (with $m_x$ being between 43 and 53 characters) and splitting it into $m_1$,$m_2$, and $m_3$ would be a valid solution. As it apparently is not: What are your security goals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the requirement is being able to reconstruct a message of $1280=160\cdot 8$ bits from $3$ parts that are among a set of $2^6$ type-able characters (say $10$ digits, $26$ uppercase letters, $26$ lowercase letters, and $2$ other characters, as in Base64), then no cryptography is required. Simply:

- split the $1280$ bits of the message into $3$ nearly equaly-sized segments, here of $427$, $427$ and $426$ bits;
- append to each segment something allowing to order the $3$ segments and making them a multiple of $6$ bits, e.g. here `00000`,`00001`, `000010`; now all messages are $432=72\cdot6$ bits, the two right bits identify the segment number;
- encode each segment as $72$ type-able characters, each encoding $6$ bits.

Decoding, identifying and pasting together the segments is easy and left as an exercise to the reader.

---

If there is the additional requirement that knowledge of $2$ of the $3$ encoded segments should give no useful information about the message, then we need some cryptography. One simple method, optimized to reduce message expansion, is:

- generate a random 128-bit $K$;
- encipher the message with key $K$ (say using [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) in [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode with implicit null IV);
- split the enciphered message in $427$, $427$ and $426$ bits data segments as above;
- XOR the first $128$ bits of each of the segments, and $K$, forming $K'$;
- splits $K'$ into $3$ segments of $42$, $43$, and $43$ bits, append these to the respective data segments, and append the terminations `00000`,`0001`, `00010`, forming $3$ segment of $474=79\cdot6$ bits, that can be identified by their rightmost 2 bits;
- encode each segment as $79$ characters each encoding $6$ bits.

Decoding is easy:

- decode each segment of $79$ characters into $3$ segments of $474$ bits;
- identify each segment by its right two bits;
- remove the terminations, rebuilt $K'$, remove these;
- XOR the first $128$ bits of each of the segments, and $K'$, forming $K$;
- rebuilt the enciphered message;
- decipher it using $K$.

If any of the encoded segments is missing, $K$ can't be formed again.

Notice that we must expand the message with random data somehow, or loose [semantic security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).

Comment: Yes, I needed that additional requirement. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a working 3-of-3 approach. I'm pretty sure tha 2-of-3 (or X-of-Y) threshold schemes require longer messages; one approach is the very similar [ssss](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/) and [SecretSplitter](http://www.moserware.com/2011/11/life-death-and-splitting-secrets.html).

Comment: @David Cary: Common threshold schemes based on [Shamir secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) are provably secure without assuming security of a block cipher, but (even in X-Y mode with X=Y) require much longer messages than what I propose. I had to craft a scheme to solve the "results are too long" issue worded in the question.

Comment: Yes, your scheme is a pretty clever way to reduce the size.